# CSS background image load fails when URL is longer

Tags: css, url, load, image

I'd humbly appreciate any help on this one.
I have a div with `background: url("../images/description_bkgrnd.jpg") repeat; display: none;`
Later this div is made visible with jQuery.
When the url looks like `http://localhost/product-name-p35/` all is OK, but when it looks something
like `http://localhost/product-name-p35/RU/` browser fails to load the image. 
In firebug I see that it is trying to load `http://localhost/product-name-p35/images/description_bkgrnd.jpg`, 
not `http://localhost/images/description_bkgrnd.jpg/`
what is to blame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url("../images/description_bkgrnd.jpg")
```

This is a relative path. When you are in the directory `http://localhost/product-name-p35/RU/`, it is loading the image from `http://localhost/product-name-p35/` (because of the `..` )

One possible way to fix this is to reference your image with an absolute path:

```
url("http://localhost/images/description_bkgrnd.jpg")
```

Another possible way is to use

```
url("/images/description_bkgrnd.jpg")
```

The `/` at the beginning makes the browser send the request to the root of the website. But do ensure that the images folder is in the website-root, or modify the URL accordingly.

Reference: http://www.ibdhost.com/help/path/

Comment: Thanks! I was thinking about it. I'm sure it will work, its just a bit ugly. It seems to make it look beautiful i'd have to have a url like this: http://localhost/RU/product-name-p35

Comment: You could use paths like
`url("/images/description_bkgrnd.jpg")`
The slash at the beginning makes it look for the images directory in the root of your website.

Answer (score 1):

.. means that you are going up one level so when you are at RU folder it will go to /product-name-p35 folder

Comment: Thanks. What could be a possible solution?

Comment: remove the .. and that's should do it